# How can I make a permanent change to a struct member when I am just passed a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable, pass-by-reference, inverted-index

I am trying to make an inverted indexer by using a hash table in C, which I understand as an array of `bucket` structs. To check whether a given bucket is "active" or not, I check to see whether I have changed its `token` member.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define HTSIZE 10

typedef struct {
    char* token;
    void* LinkedListPtr;
} bucket;

int hash_function(char* token)
{
    int hfret = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++) 
    { 
        hfret += token[i] % HTSIZE;
    }

    printf("hashed to %d\n", hfret % HTSIZE);
    return hfret % HTSIZE;
}

void check_modify_bucket(char* tok, bucket** htb)
{
    bucket* deref = *htb;
    int key = hash_function(tok); //returns 7 for "stories"
    if (deref[key].token == NULL)
    {
        deref[key].token = malloc(6);
        strcpy(deref[key].token, "hello");
        printf("after change (within callee): %s\n", deref[key].token);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bucket* hash = calloc(HTSIZE, sizeof(bucket)); 

    check_modify_bucket("stories", &hash);
    printf("after change (from caller): %s\n", hash[3].token); 

    check_modify_bucket("stories", &hash);
    printf("after change (from caller): %s\n", hash[3].token);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: embarrassingly, in the course of making a "minimally complete and verifiable example", I made a minimally complete and verifiable example that works as intended. Originally my question was more abstract, as I was trying to debug a larger and more complex program.

The behavior that I saw in my own program was, by analogy, that `check_modify_bucket()` would be able to see its own change to `token` after making it; and the caller `main()` would be able to see the change as well. But when `check_modify_bucket` would be called again, it would incorrectly see that `token` for the same specific hash `key` as NULL.

Comment: Are you sure `hash_function` is returning `3`?

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Particularly `new_table` and `hash_function`. You have described them functioning correctly but we need to verify for ourselves (since by definition you don't know where the problem is).